# How to do document.createElement in ReScript

Tags: javascript, reason, rescript

ReScript seems to be a better way to write JS code, but I am not able to find what should be a simple single line of docs.

How do I call functions like `document.createElement()`?

I tried Js.document, Dom.document, by looking at this page: https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/api, but that code gives an error in the playground:

> The value `document` can't be found in Js
> The value `document` can't be found in Dom

Answer (score 1):

To call JS functions you'll need to use ReScript's [JS interop](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/interop-cheatsheet#global-value). In this case, you can use the `external` keyword and  `@val`/`@scope` attributes to get a ReScript function that will call `document.createElement` when invoked:

```
@val @scope(("window", "document"))
external createElement: string => unit = "createElement"

createElement("div")
```

This will be transformed to

```js
window.document.createElement('div');
```

For quick prototyping, you can also just use `external` and interact with the objects like RS Objects directly:

```
@val external document: 'a = "document"

document["createElement"]("div")
```

Check out the [interop cheatsheet](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/interop-cheatsheet) and [docs for `external`](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/external#tips--tricks) for more common patterns.

Comment: I followed the above advice of using `external`. I have correctly typed the return value of `createElement` as `Dom.element`, yet I am not able to access properties like outerHTML which are mentioned on Mozilla. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong? Code is [here](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=AINwhgNgBMDODGB7ADgUwBToEQHcCWAdgCaI5YA0UWJ8ArgLaoEAuWAlGwFCoAezqAJwKQo8AajD8AohFSMWALiixmAwgHMoAXgB8UACKJ6AOlSz5zbVTETp5pq06dZlonhBWbk1DLkPsbiDsnIHGiLT8AgASACoAsgAynAD0yaEAZngCKgDCABZ4EEQpae7GKgCesk5AA).

Comment: ReScript provides the `Dom` module as a common set of opaque types for low-level UI libraries to work with; like it says on [the docs](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/api/dom), they don't provide any actual functionality. If you'd like to interact imperatively with the DOM, you'll need to write most of the actual code in JS and then expose a few entrypoints for ReScript (that's what the `Dom` opaque types are for, to make sure your RS code passes the expected value types). As @mr-polywhirl mentioned, the path of least resistance is to use an existing lib like React.

Comment: @vinay-deshmukh , you will need to understand several different concepts before you can understand what you are doing wrong here. Stack Overflow is not a great place to have that discussion. I highly recommend asking this question on the ReScript forum, where people can have an extended discussion: https://forum.rescript-lang.org/ . Finally, if you just want to start using something immediately, try https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-webapi-incubator

Answer (score 1):

you can use bs-webapi

```
open Webapi.Dom
open Belt

document
->Document.asHtmlDocument
->Option.flatMap(document => document->HtmlDocument.body)
->Option.map(body => {
  let root = document->Document.createElement("div", _)
  root->Element.setId("app")
  root->Element.appendChild(body)
})
->ignore
```

Comment: where does "lowercase" `document` come from?

Comment: It's exposed under Webapi.Dom

Answer (score -1):

Since re-script is powered by React (JSX) and not standard ECMA JavaScript, I do not think you can use calls like `document.createElement`.

Instead, you should [create the element](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/react/latest/elements-and-jsx) via:

```
let element = <h1> {React.string("Hello World")} </h1>
```

This transpiles into the following:

```js
var element = React.createElement("h1", undefined, "Hello World");
```

---

I modified the default Playground script:

```
module Button = {
  @react.component
  let make = (~count: int) => {
    let times = switch count {
    | 1 => "once"
    | 2 => "twice"
    | n => Belt.Int.toString(n) ++ " times"
    }
    let msg = "Click me " ++ times
    let element = <button> {React.string(msg)} </button>
    element
  }
}
```

Comment: React.createElement is not equivalent or even close to document.createElement. As I had mentioned, I am trying to use ReScript in JS, and not in a React project.